# Alignment div horizontally, stop floating on window resize

Tags: html, css

A very stupid simple question, i know, but.. sorry :)

I have 2 div, one for list on the left and one for details on the right. When i resize window, the div on the right float under the first one, i would like to keep the alignment, even with a scroll bar.
How achieve this?

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="list">
      ...table list...
   </div>
   <div id="details">
      ...table details...
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent div{
   float:left;
   clear:none;
}
```

Comment: If they have explicit widths, set a `min-width` on the parent, otherwise, try using `inline-block`s instead, with the flavor of `white-space: nowrap` on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.table{
    display:table
}

.table-cell{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" class="table">
    <div id="list" class="table-cell">...table list...</div>
    <div id="list" class="table-cell">...table details...</div>
</div>
```

This will keep both divs aligned horizontally when you resize the browser.

Or keep it really simple...

CSS:

```
#parent > div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. should be `#parent > div` not `.parent > div`. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hr1fhjck/

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `display:inline-block` to your css will fix this.

EDIT:
Actually, to use this method, you will want to remove the float and give both child elements this display property.

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="my_block" id="list">
      ...table list...
   </div>
   <div class="my_block" id="details">
      ...table details...
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.my_block {
    display:inline-block;
}
```